# refreshing a question that is not answered yet

Tags: support

I have noticed that the questions being asked on the weekend didn't been answered as fast as the working days.
So my question is there a way to refresh an answered question to be back in the new questions queue so people can see it and answer it quickly instead of buried in the unanswered question for some time?

Comment: What do you mean *"refresh"*? If you edit a question it gets bumped back to the front page, but **do not** spam trivial edits to try to get eyes on your post.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so editing it can make it back at the top of the front page like it has been asked today?

Comment: Not quite, but a *legitimate edit* to add more useful information may get you more attention.

Comment: i want it back to the top front page like it is new

Comment: Oh. Well... tough?

Comment: Wouldn't that bury the Monday morning questions in the weekend "requeued" items? And with the 24hr operation what would you consider weekend: when all of the world has weekend (only 25 hrs each week) or when any pars has weekend (71 hrs), or weekend in some particular timezone (and  UTC would  be the only real candidate).